# Parsing XML file using Xpath in jdk1.4

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I found the following easy solution to extracting values from XML file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

public class XPathExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
          IOException, XPathExpressionException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("c:/temp/books.xml");

    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr 
     = xpath.compile("//book[author='Neal Stephenson']/title/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
    }

  }

}
```

This uses xpath to extract all books title where the author is Neal Stephenson from the following xml

```
<inventory>
<book year="2000">
    <title>Snow Crash</title>
    <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
    <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
    <isbn>0553380958</isbn>
    <price>14.95</price>
</book>

<book year="2005">
    <title>Burning Tower</title>
    <author>Larry Niven</author>
    <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
    <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
    <isbn>0743416910</isbn>
    <price>5.99</price>
</book>

<book year="1995">
    <title>Zodiac</title>
    <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
    <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
    <isbn>0553573862</isbn>
    <price>7.50</price>
</book>

<!-- more books... -->

</inventory>
```

Now this works fine on JDK5 but i am using jdk 1.4
Can this be converted to the java 1.4 equivalent?

All i am trying to do is extract a value from an xml element. For example, in the above xml, i just want something that is the equivalent of getElementByTag("title").

Thanks

Comment: +1 for Neal Stephenson (I could not resist :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick google resulted in links like [this](http://jaxp.java.net/1.4/1.4.2/ReleaseNotes.html) and [this](http://people.apache.org/~edwingo/jaxp-faq.html) which confirm that JAXP can be downloaded separately and run on top of JDK 1.4.2.  You might run into configuration problems as mentioned in the apache link.  Good luck!

Comment: Is it not possible without external downloads?

Comment: Sorry mate i am slightly confused. I thought JAXP is already in 1.4. See this http://www.esus.com/javaindex/j2se/jdk1.2/jaxp/jaxp.html is the DOM parser in 1.4 not part of JAXP?

Comment: JAXP is just an interface. You also need an implementation, and the XPath implementation javax.xml.xpath was introduced in JDK 5. That being said, you can download implementations for 1.4.

Comment: Hi mark, 
Please see http://jaxp.java.net/1.3/Updating.html#java-14 towards the end of the document it says that an implementation of JAXP is built in to the jdk1.4. I dont quite understand the difference in the downloadable implementation and the implementation included in jdk1.4 and also why i cant access the built in implementation

Comment: I thought you wanted XPath support.  Xpath support is available in JAXP from 1.3 I believe.  Whatever is built in Jdk 1.4 is JAXP 1.1 which would not have Xpath support.